# ¿Mostrar o ocultar registros con AJAX .. PARA UN BUSCADOR?

Tags: php

una pantalla que permita hacer búsquedas de disponibilidad de vehículos, donde el cliente pueda escoger el auto, y diga la fecha y hora de recogida y entrega. El resultado de búsqueda debe actualizarse por Ajax, apenas se cambien las condiciones.

no resultado AJAX.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

index.php

```
    $obj = new Arriendo_autos();

    print "<h1>Arriendo de autos</h1>";

    print "<form action='#' method='post'>";

    print "Fecha de arriendo";

    print "<input type='text' id='fechaa' name='fechaa'>";

    print "Fecha de devolución";

    print "<input type='text' id='fechad' name='fechad'>";

    print "<br>";

    print "<input type='submit' id='btn' value='Buscar'>";

    print "</from>";

    print "<div id='responsecontainer' align='center'>";

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
       function mostrarBD() {
        $.ajax({
         url: 'buscador.php',
         type: 'get',
         datatype: 'html',
         data: {search: $('#btn').val()},
         success: function(response) {
           $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
          }, 
         error : function() {
            alert("Error!");
         }
       });
      }
      $('#btn').click(function(){
        mostrarBD();
      });

      $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            mostrarBD();
      });
    });   
</script>
```

buscador.php

```
$obj = new Arriendo_autos();

$arriendos = $obj->getBuscar();

        print "<table>";
        if (is_array($arriendos) || is_object($arriendos))
        {

            foreach ($arriendos  as $arriendo) 
            {
                print "<tr>";
                    print "<td>".$arriendo["titulo"]." <a href='#'>Reservar</a></td>";
                print "</tr>";
            }

        }
        print "</table>";
```

function.php

```
function getBuscar()
    {

        $fechaa = (isset($_GET['fechaa']) ? $_GET['fechaa'] : null);
        $fechad = (isset($_GET['fechad']) ? $_GET['fechad'] : null);

        echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM arriendos AS a INNER JOIN incidentes AS i ON a.idarriendo = i.idarriendos WHERE a.fecha_arriendo >= '".$fechaa."' AND a.fecha_devolucion <= '".$fechad."'"; 

        $res = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        if(isset($data))
        {
          return $data; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en cada uno de los archivos, he corregido algunos pero como no tengo como probarlo no sé si esta vez funcionará del todo.

index.php

```
print "<h1>Arriendo de autos</h1>";
print "Fecha de arriendo";
print "<input type='text' id='fechaa' name='fechaa'>";
print "Fecha de devolución";
print "<input type='text' id='fechad' name='fechad'>";
print "<br>";
print "<input type='button' id='btn' value='Buscar'>";
print "<div id='responsecontainer' align='center'></div>";
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'buscador.php',
            type: 'get',
            datatype: 'html',
            data: {fechaa: $('#fechaa').val(), fechad:$('#fechad').val()},
            success: function(response) {
                $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
            }, 
            error : function() {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
    });
});  
</script>
```

buscador.php

```
$obj = new Arriendo_autos();

$arriendos = $obj->getBuscar($_GET['fechaa'], $_GET['fechad']);

print "<table>";
if (is_array($arriendos) || is_object($arriendos))
{

    foreach ($arriendos  as $arriendo) 
   {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>".$arriendo["titulo"]." <a href='#'>Reservar</a></td>";
        print "</tr>";
   }

}
print "</table>";
```

function.php

```
function getBuscar($fechaa, $fechab)
{
    echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM arriendos AS a INNER JOIN incidentes AS i ON a.idarriendo = i.idarriendos WHERE a.fecha_arriendo >= '".$fechaa."' AND a.fecha_devolucion <= '".$fechad."'"; 

    $res = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    if(isset($data))
    {
      return $data; 
    }
}
```

Te recomiendo que revises si `buscador.php` retorna los valores correctos accediendo al archivo de este modo **buscador.php?fechaa=2016/20/01&fechab=2016/21/01** (escribiendo las fechas correctamente)

Una vez que sepas que ese archivo funciona como corresponde, vuelve al index.php y realiza la búsqueda con el formulario.

Comment: si funciona bien, entiendo claro. muchas gracias